# Finding Form Tab in Which FIeld Resides Using Server-Side SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I find myself in a situation where I need to group a couple fields together within a field group on a standard record form, but also need to be able to allow users to modify the forms to change which tab these fields sit under. However, I see no way within SuiteScript to be able to determine under which tab a field may currently be based on the loaded form. I'd rather force the field to be located under a predetermined tab on the record form, but the powers that be are telling me I can't force these fields into a specific location.

Has anyone found a way to do this? I'm not expecting anyone to have found a way to make this work, but it can't hurt to ask.

For example, to help illustrate the issue, in one situation there is a custom field added to Sales Orders. Originally I had the field set underneath the "Billing" tab, but I later found that some NetSuite accounts don't have the feature enabled that adds that tab. I was using SuiteScript during the BeforeLoad event on a UE script to add the field to a field group in order to separate out the field from other fields. But, doing that ends up forcing the field into whatever tab the field group is added to. So, wherever the field is moved to in the record's custom form, it gets moved to the tab the field grouped is added under. So, I was hoping that there was a way to determine under which tab the field currently exists during the BeforeLoad event so I could add the field group to that tab and get the field moved into the field group. At present I see no way to accomplish this, but I'm hopeful that maybe someone has done this successfully.